# Calculate time values in a single Google Spreadsheet cell

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to add two times, or durations, in one line in a Google Spreadsheet?

Something like:

```
=1:14:25+0:17:12
```

I know that I can use the *time* command in-line, and that I can add times from two separate cells, but I was wondering if there was a simpler and more elegant way to add two times when entering them in the same cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use:

`="1:14:25"+"0:17:12"`

Comment: On a scale of zero to elegant I'd rate this tidy-ish.

Comment: Thanks, AdamL, that's what I was looking for! I actually tried this before, but it didn't occur to me that I then need to change the cell's format to "Time" to get the output in hh:mm:ss, rather than just a number...

Answer (score 2):

With the `TIMEVALUE` formula, you're able to make time based calculations within a cell.

### Formula

```
=TIMEVALUE("01:00") + TIMEVALUE("02:15")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[TIMEVALUE](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1bF5ThYEOanjW3AW9ckX9h4is3T9XeHT5Z95Q9PAzGVk/edit?usp=sharing)**

### Reference

- [Google Sheets Help: TIMEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350)